# Redirect visitor based on GeoIP location

Tags: geo-location

I'm using Sitecore 8.0 with GeoIP service. I'd like to redirect user to a specific sitecore item depending on his location. 
I didn't see any redirect rule in personalization rules. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can find location based on visitor IP and can implement redirect condition for a particular url.
e.g:

```
System.Net.IPAddress ipAddress = null;
string country = string.Empty;

if (System.Net.IPAddress.TryParse(Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"], out ipAddress))
{
    Sitecore.Analytics.Lookups.GeoIpOptions geoIpOptions = new Sitecore.Analytics.Lookups.GeoIpOptions();
    geoIpOptions.Ip = ipAddress;
    Sitecore.Analytics.Lookups.GeoIpResult geoIpResult1 = Sitecore.Analytics.Lookups.GeoIpManager.GetGeoIpData(geoIpOptions);
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    Sitecore.Analytics.Lookups.GeoIpResult geoIpResult = Sitecore.Analytics.Lookups.GeoIpManager.GetGeoIpData(geoIpOptions);

    if (geoIpResult != null)
    {
        country = geoIpResult.GeoIpData.Country;
    }

    if (country == "HK")
    {
        string link = "";
        Item redirectItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(link);      
    }
```